# Symfony2 Sonata Admin - Disable validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony, sonata-admin

I have an application accepting user input. The form is setup with a custom validator to verify the submissions are acceptable.

How can I disable this validation when using Sonata Admin?

When users submit this data, it is checked for a variety of things. One being that it doesn't already exist in the database. When I am attempting to edit any of these in Sonata Admin the update fails because of this validation.

Thanks

Comment: Got any code and or errors for us?

Comment: do you want to disable server side validation or client side?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable client side "html 5 validation", you can add this to your `config.yml`:

```
sonata_admin:
    options:
        html5_validate: false
```

(See https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's better you post some code up here to understand your question. Anyway, with my guess, this may help in symfony2 [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#disabling-validation):

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => false,
    ));
}
```

You can try something 'validation' => false (this may wrong), in your admin class.

Comment: That works for form types but not for the sonata FormMapper.